# curl or wget gets invalid jpg image but browser gets valid image

Tags: php, image, curl, wget

I run command like

```
wget https://odis.homeaway.com/odis/listing/5895882c-6c65-47f5-b782-e13b8246e4aa.c10.jpg
```

I try to get above image using curl, the returned image is invalid jpg image. When I try with browser and save image as, I get valid jpg image. Even when I try with file_get_contents it returns false.

```
    $image = 'https://odis.homeaway.com/odis/listing/5895882c-6c65-47f5-b782-e13b8246e4aa.c10.jpg'
    $image_data = file_get_contents($image);
    try {
        echo 'saving';
        $image1 = imagecreatefromjpeg($image_data);

    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo 'error';
    }
```

How to get this image with `curl`, `wget`, or `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save image from url with curl PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6476212/save-image-from-url-with-curl-php)

Comment: No I am trying same code in case of curl, but I get invalid jpg image saying Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x89, I tried saving in png/gif, still does not work

Comment: I have tried with all option 1. wget 2. curl 3. file_get_contents, In each case I get invalid image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [can't get image using php CURL with SSL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33555219/cant-get-image-using-php-curl-with-ssl)

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a bug with the `odis.homeaway.com` server, you should send their webmaster a bugreport.

their server ALWAYS send the image in https://odis.homeaway.com/odis/listing/5895882c-6c65-47f5-b782-e13b8246e4aa.c10.jpg  gzip compressed, even if the client did NOT specify `accept-encoding: gzip`. wget doesn't support gzip compression at all, but curl does. until they fix their server, you can tell curl to decompress it for you automatically by setting the `--compressed` argument in the command line version, or setting `CURLOPT_ENCODING=>'gzip'` in the curl_ api, or running it through gzdecode(), eg `$image_data = gzdecode(file_get_contents($image));` (the gzdecode() method is **NOT** recommended, because this will stop working once they actually fix their  server, and only works now because their server is bugged). the reason your browser isn't affected by the bug, is that all mainstream browser always sends `Accept-Encoding: gzip` (and others) by default.

edit: originally i mentioned `gzuncompress()`, not `gzdecode()`, that was a mistake, the correct decompression function is `gzdecode()`.